# How to find the supremum of this set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k \in \Bbb N$ be fixed and $S=\{k^2x(1-x^2)^k\ : x \in [0,1]\}$ I'm trying to find $\sup S$ and at which $x \in [0,1]$ one obtains this supremum.

This $\sup$ is not at $x=0, 1$ because $k^2x(1-x^2)^k=0$, for those values of $x$, and for example, for $x=1/2$, $k^2x(1-x^2)^k>0$.

Comment: haha are you just going down the list of your homework problems? Maybe try to find maxima and minima using calculus.

Comment: No, if you see it's the same sequence of my last question. I'm dealing with just one problem of a sequence of functions, but it is a long problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming $k>0$, $x\mapsto k^2x(1-x^2)^k$ is is a positive function which only vanishes at $x=0,1$, and a continuous function which therefore achieves its supremum on $[0,1]$. Hence the supremum is a local maximum of this smooth function, which can be found by differentiating it:
$$0 = f^\prime(x) = k^2(1-x^2)^k - 2k^3x^2(1-x^2)^{k-1} = k^2(1-x^2)^{k-1}(1-(1+2k)x^2),$$
which is achieved at $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2k}}$. The supremum (maximum) is therefore
$$\frac{k^2(2k)^k}{(1+2k)^{k+1/2}}$$

Comment: No, I was wrong, thanks.

Comment: Should I calculate $f''$ to check that $f''(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2k}})<0$ to be sure it is a maximum?

Comment: We might, but in this case that's redundant (the smooth function has to attain a maximum in $(0,1)$, and has but a single critical point there).